# VBA Excel procedure very slow for some, fast for others

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a procedure that copies data from one workbook to another, skipping rows that don't contain certain values in column F. Everything works perfectly for me and some of my co-workers (runs in under 5 seconds), but for others it takes upwards of 1 minute to run. Any reason this might be happening? Here is my current code, thank you:

```
Sub ImportForecastData()

    Application.StatusBar = "Importing Data..."
    
    Dim sourceFilename As String, sFileName As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, importWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim openBefore As Boolean
    openBefore = False
    sFileName = "redactedName.xlsm"
    filePath = "F:\Redacted\redactedName.xlsm"
    
    Set importWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
        TestStr = Dir(filePath)
        
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If TestStr = "" Then
        
    Else
    
        ' Only open workbook if closed, otherwise re-open is not needed, and will slow down refresh.
        If AlreadyOpen(sFileName) Then
            Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks(sFileName)
            openBefore = True
        Else
            Set sourceWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        End If
        
    
        ' copy data from source to this workbook
        Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
        Set thisSheet = importWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        ' clear previous data
        thisSheet.Range("A4:J198").ClearContents
        
        Dim iNumOfRows As Integer, iStartFromRow As Integer, currentRow As Integer
        iNumOfRows = sourceSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row '- counts used rows starting from A4
        
        For iStartFromRow = 4 To iNumOfRows
        
            If (sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value) = "redacted" Or (sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value) = "redacted2" Or (sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value) = "redacted3" Then
    
                currentRow = thisSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "A").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "A").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "B").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "B").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "C").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "C").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "D").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "D").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "E").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "F").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "G").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "G").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "H").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "H").Value
                
                ' Offset to skip non-redacted column in sourceSheet
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "I").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "J").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "J").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "K").Value
    
            End If
        
        Next iStartFromRow

        ' Close source workbook if it was closed before Refresh, otherwise keep open for continued work.
        If openBefore = False Then
            sourceWorkbook.Close
        End If
        
        MsgBox ("Import Complete")
        
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    
End Sub
```

I also have this small function that checks if the sourceWorkbook is open, to avoid re-opening it.

```
Function AlreadyOpen(sFname As String) As Boolean

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Workbooks(sFname)
    AlreadyOpen = Not wkb Is Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Comment: Probably just system limitations. Might have less RAM or more RAM is being used at the time the macro is run. Could also be that a file is more localized to your system or cached. Have you tried adding `application.screenupdating = false` to the beginning of your code `and application.screenupdating = true` to the bottom? This will help your speed.

Comment: Where is this code located? in `thisWorkbook`, `SourceWorkbook` or a third workbook? And if you could explain, in your own words, what the code in the `For Next` loop is supposed to do. I do understand the rest of the code.

Comment: You should avoid using `thisworkbook` as a variable.  It is a standard name to refer to the workbook where the code resides.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the procedure is called upon the default `Workbook_Open` within `thisWorkbook`. My `For Next` loop runs through every row in the `sourceWorkbook` from row 4 to the last used row, and copies data cell by cell into `thisWorkbook`, skipping rows that don't meet the listed criteria in column F. I did cell by cell instead of entire row because `sourceWorkbook` has one extra column that I don't want to copy over. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Are all your co-workers in the same office?  If some are working from home they may have a poor bandwidth thus not able to open the workbook as quickly.

Comment: @DarrellH thank you, I did not know this. I've changed the variable name to `importWorkbook`.

Comment: @Jan Some are working from home, but the reports of slow refresh times are coming from a mix of in-office and at-home users. I'm guessing it's a combination of poor bandwidth and less RAM that **Mech** alluded to earlier. Can I do anything to combat this?

Comment: If you are going to be doing this with large datasets or a large number of external files then you will eventually want to move to working with ADO connections instead of opening workbooks. See here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247866/creating-a-values-only-copy-of-an-excel-workbook-without-opening-it/247872#247872

Comment: You could change to a Variant Array approach.   1. Copy the source data to an array. 2. Create another array for the results. 3. Loop the source array, fill the destination array with matching data. 4. Place the destination array on the sheet.  This will be an order of magnitude faster.  There are lots of examples on SO

Comment: @JackMorris did any of these answers help? If so, please be sure to mark the answer as accepted so others can find the solution if they are having similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `application.screenupdating = False` / `application.screenupdating = True` to your code as below. It will stop the screen from updating as the macro progresses and should help speed up the process.

```
Sub ImportForecastData()
    application.screenupdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Importing Data..."
    
    Dim sourceFilename As String, sFileName As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, thisWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim openBefore As Boolean
    openBefore = False
    sFileName = "redactedName.xlsm"
    filePath = "F:\Redacted\redactedName.xlsm"
    
    Set thisWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
        TestStr = Dir(filePath)
        
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If TestStr = "" Then
        
    Else
    
        ' Only open workbook if closed, otherwise re-open is not needed, and will slow down refresh.
        If AlreadyOpen(sFileName) Then
            Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks(sFileName)
            openBefore = True
        Else
            Set sourceWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        End If
        
    
        ' copy data from source to this workbook
        Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
        Set thisSheet = thisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        ' clear previous data
        thisSheet.Range("A4:J198").ClearContents
        
        Dim iNumOfRows As Integer, iStartFromRow As Integer, currentRow As Integer
        iNumOfRows = sourceSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row '- counts used rows starting from A4
        
        For iStartFromRow = 4 To iNumOfRows
        
            If (sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value) = "redacted" Or (sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value) = "redacted2" Or (sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value) = "redacted3" Then
    
                currentRow = thisSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "A").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "A").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "B").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "B").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "C").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "C").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "D").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "D").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "E").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "F").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "F").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "G").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "G").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "H").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "H").Value
                
                ' Offset to skip non-redacted column in sourceSheet
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "I").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "J").Value
                thisSheet.Cells(currentRow, "J").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(iStartFromRow, "K").Value
    
            End If
        
        Next iStartFromRow

        ' Close source workbook if it was closed before Refresh, otherwise keep open for continued work.
        If openBefore = False Then
            sourceWorkbook.Close
        End If
        
        MsgBox ("Import Complete")
        
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    application.screenupdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding this cut my procedure runtime in half. Waiting on results from co-workers. Is there anything else I can do to combat slower system/network configurations?

Comment: it looks like there are numerous way to optimize this script, 1° reference the external worksheet using "with" like "with sourceSheet" and "end with" 2° the If instruction could be shorter using worksheet.function "OR" or instr(redacted, redacted2, redacted3)... If you really want it to go really fast, you copy all the data into an array, that would be two arrays and you do comparaisons from there 3° if you have enough RAM, else using SQL could make things better and more simple for this since there is not a lot of logic

Answer (score 0):

You could change to a Variant Array approach.

1. Copy the source data to an array.
2. Create another array for the results.
3. Loop the source array, fill the destination array with matching data.
4. Place the destination array on the sheet.

Something like this.
<sub>Note: I've made various other minor chages to tidy up your code</sub>

```
Option Explicit ' Add this as the very first line in your module

Sub ImportForecastData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Importing Data..."
    
    Dim sourceFilename As String, sFileName As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, destWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim openBefore As Boolean
        
    openBefore = False
    sFileName = "redactedName.xlsm"
    filePath = "F:\Redacted\" & sFileName
    
    If Dir(filePath) <> vbNullString Then
        Set destWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        ' Only open workbook if closed, otherwise re-open is not needed, and will slow down refresh.
        If AlreadyOpen(sFileName) Then
            Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks(sFileName)
            openBefore = True
        Else
            Set sourceWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        End If
    
        ' copy data from source to this workbook
        Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
        Set thisSheet = destWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        Dim sourceRange As Range
        Dim destRange As Range
        Dim sourceData As Variant
        Dim destData As Variant
        
        ' clear previous data
        thisSheet.Range("A4:J" & thisSheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents ' Assumes no other data below row 198
        Dim iSourceRow As Long, iDestRow As Long
        With sourceSheet
            Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown)).Resize(, 11)
        End With
        Set destRange = thisSheet.Cells(4, 1)
        sourceData = sourceRange.Value2
        ReDim destData(1 To UBound(sourceData, 1), 1 To UBound(sourceData, 2))
        
        iDestRow = thisSheet.Cells(thisSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For iSourceRow = 1 To UBound(sourceData, 1)
            If sourceData(iSourceRow, 6) = "redacted" Or _
               sourceData(iSourceRow, 6) = "redacted2" Or _
               sourceData(iSourceRow, 6) = "redacted3" Then
                
                iDestRow = iDestRow + 1
                destData(iDestRow, 1) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 1)
                destData(iDestRow, 2) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 2)
                destData(iDestRow, 3) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 3)
                destData(iDestRow, 4) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 4)
                destData(iDestRow, 5) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 5)
                destData(iDestRow, 6) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 6)
                destData(iDestRow, 7) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 7)
                destData(iDestRow, 8) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 8)
                ' Offset to skip non-redacted column in sourceSheet
                destData(iDestRow, 9) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 10)
                destData(iDestRow, 10) = sourceData(iSourceRow, 11)
            End If
        Next iSourceRow
        
        Set destRange = destRange.Resize(UBound(destData, 1), UBound(destData, 2))
        destRange = destData
        ' Close source workbook if it was closed before Refresh, otherwise keep open for continued work.
        If Not openBefore Then
            sourceWorkbook.Close
        End If
        
        MsgBox ("Import Complete")
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = False
    destWorkbook.Save ' you ment to save the book, right?
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

### Copy From Other Workbook

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportForecastData()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcFullName As String = "F:\Test\redactedName.xlsm"
    Const srcName As String = "redactedName.xlsm"
    Const srcID As Variant = 1 ' e.g. 1,2,"Sheet1","Sheet2","Data" ...
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 4
    Const srcLastRowCol As Long = 1
    Dim srcCols As Variant: srcCols = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11)
    ' Target
    Const tgtID As Variant = 1 ' e.g. 1,2,"Sheet1","Sheet2","Data" ...
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A4"
    ' Other
    Const CritColIndex As Long = 5
    Dim Crit As Variant: Crit = Array("redacted", "redacted2", "redacted3")
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Change some application settings.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Importing Data..."
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim wbS As Workbook, wbWasNotOpen As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbS = Workbooks(srcName)
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        wbWasNotOpen = True
        Set wbS = Workbooks.Open(srcFullName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wbS.Worksheets(srcID)
    
    ' Define Last Row Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, srcLastRowCol).End(xlUp)
    If rng.Row < srcFirstRow Then GoTo LastAboveFirst
    Set rng = src.Range(src.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcLastRowCol), rng)
    
    ' Write Source Columns to Source Jagged Array.
    Dim ubc As Long: ubc = UBound(srcCols)
    Dim Source As Variant: ReDim Source(ubc)
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To ubc
        Source(j) = rng.Offset(, srcCols(j) - srcLastRowCol).Value
    Next j
    
    ' Write data from Source Array to Target Array.
    Dim ubs As Long: ubs = UBound(Source(0))
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To ubs, 1 To UBound(srcCols) + 1)
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To ubs
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Source(CritColIndex)(i, 1), Crit, 0)) _
          Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 0 To ubc
                Target(k, j + 1) = Source(j)(i, 1)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if no criteria value was found.
    If k = 0 Then GoTo NoRedact
    
    ' Write data Target Array to Target Range.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtID)
    Set rng = tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(, ubc + 1)
    rng.Resize(tgt.Rows.Count - tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Row + 1).ClearContents
    rng.Resize(k).Value = Target
    wb.Save
        
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Import Complete.", vbInformation
    
SafeExit:
    
    ' Close Source Workbook if it initially was not open.
    If wbWasNotOpen Then wbS.Close False ' False means without saving.
        
    ' Change (revert) some application settings.
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub
    
' Labels
LastAboveFirst:
    MsgBox "Last row is above first row."
    GoTo SafeExit

NoRedact:
    MsgBox "No data found"
    GoTo SafeExit
    
End Sub
```